# How to Apply a Normal Map to a Portion of a Mesh?

Tags: dictionary, html5-canvas, three.js, textures, normals

The question says it all. I want to only apply a normal map to a a portion (a few select faces) of a mesh.

The normal maps currently are all 512 x 512 and come from a canvas.

What are some ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at THREE.MeshFaceMaterial will be a good place to start. This will allow you to use multiple textures on a single mesh. I'm having trouble finding good documentation, but you can check out [this little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/theo/VsWb9/) on jsfiddle to see it in action. Instead of just defining a color in each individual material, you will define it's normalMap to be your intended normal map.

Then each face can be mapped to a specific texture manually in our example using code like:

```
cube.geometry.faces[desiredFaceIndex].materialIndex = desiredMaterialIndex
```

There are probably much slicker methods to set this up by modifying the mesh before we pass it to Three.js. I believe that if you have created the model to expect multiple textures, you can just apply them using the method shown in the fiddle to reach your desired result. Good luck!

Comment: Nice thanks =]  If I assign the same map to multiple faces it wont repeat for each face will it?